# SSIS Custom Task Error - Code: 0xC001F02A Source: Package Description: Cannot create a task from XML for task

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to create a custom package.  I made a simple test package, to send an email using outlook interop. I was able to get the task to show up in the ssis toolbox by switching the server version to 2012. however I get the following error when trying to run it in vs on my local machine,

> Error: 0xC0010026 at Custom Task: The task has failed to load. The
> contact information for this task is "".

I then tried to run it in dtexec to see if i could get more information.

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.7001.0
> for 32-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  3:53:50 PM Error: 2021-01-14 15:53:50.27    Code: 0xC001F02A
> Source: Package     Description: Cannot create a task from XML for
> task "Custom Task", type "SSISCustomTaskLibrary.CustomTaskTest,
> SSISCustomTaskLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=4fdef094ddc47664" due to error 0x80070057 "The
> parameter is incorrect.". End Error Error: 2021-01-14 15:53:50.27
> Code: 0xC0010018    Source: Custom Task     Description: Failed to
> load task "Custom Task", type "". The contact information for this
> task is "". End Error Error: 2021-01-14 15:53:50.28    Code:
> 0xC0010026    Source: Custom Task     Description: The task has failed
> to load. The contact information for this task is "". End Error Error:
> 2021-01-14 15:53:50.28    Code: 0xC0024107    Source: Custom Task
> Description: There were errors during task validation. End Error
> Error: 2021-01-14 15:53:50.28    Code: 0xC0010025    Source: Package
> Description: The package cannot execute because it contains tasks that
> failed to load. End Error DTExec: The package execution returned
> DTSER_FAILURE (1). Started:  3:53:50 PM Finished: 3:53:50 PM Elapsed:
> 0.109 seconds

so I fiddled some more and found that if after I loaded the task I switched back to 2019, task disappeared from the toolbox but it ran successfully.  however the properties were not working and show an error for every property. I took a screenshot and added it to the project which is located here, https://github.com/w-storey/SSISCustomTaskTestSolution.git

I am using visual studio 2019 with the data tools installed. I added the dll to the gac using these commands

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8
> Tools\gacutil" /u SSISCustomTaskLibrary "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\gacutil" /iF
> "*\source\repos\Tests\SSISCustomTaskTestSolution\SSISCustomTaskLibrary\bin\Release\SSISCustomTaskLibrary.dll"
> copy
> "*\source\repos\Tests\SSISCustomTaskTestSolution\SSISCustomTaskLibrary\bin\Release\SSISCustomTaskLibrary.dll"
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks"

so the question is how can I get this task custom task to work?